# PDE transformation by change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The equation $x^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}-2xy\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}+y^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}=0$ can be transformed by substituting variables

$\begin{cases}u=xy\\v=\frac{1}{y}\end{cases}$

I have attached my solution in the images below showing how I arrived to $$2v^2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v^2}+v\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}-u\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=0$$

I expected both second partials of u and v to vanish and have been stuck wondering if this could have a simpler form without second partials, or something with mixed second partials.
 Any sort of pointers on this would be helpful

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the transformation coordinates are correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. If u=xy and v=1/y are the coordinates, then yes I'm sure, its supposed to be them. If you mean my final answer is the coordinates, then no, I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake is in the beginning.

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \color{red}{0} \ne \frac{1}{u}$$

Second, your chain rule application isn't quite correct. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133423/method-of-characteristics-second-order-derivatives-need-help-finding/3133512#3133512) for my full derivation.

As a reminder, note that since

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(z) = \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$

we have

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial }{\partial v}\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\right)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +  \color{blue}{\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}} $$

As a result

$$ \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} =  \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \color{blue}{2\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}} + \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v^2}\left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2 +  \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} $$

See if you can find the remaining derivatives in the same way....

---

The correct derivatives are

\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} &= y^2  \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2} \\
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} &= xy \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2} - \frac{1}{y} \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} &= x^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2} - \frac{2x}{y^2} \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u\partial v} + \frac{1}{y^4} \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v^2} + \frac{2}{y^3} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}
\end{align}

And the final equation turns out to be

$$ v^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v^2} + 2v \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} - 2u\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} = 0 $$

Comment: Your method has been very helpful to me as it explained it better than the textbook used. I got the same result as you this way, except for the mixed partial. I've edited your post slightly, but I'm still not sure about your mixed partial. When I did it, I ended up with −2u(∂z/∂u) as well in the final equation?
This makes it more similar to my original answer just that the factor 2 is shifted

Comment: @TheMercury79 You're right. That was my mistake.

Comment: thank you for all your help